# Java - nested if/else if - Variables never instantiate

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm a relative beginner when it comes to programming and I've had a really good grasp on every concept up until this point. My task for this project is to make a tax code based on different laws in different counties, and I have to do this using nested if/else statements. Here's the code I have for this.

```
public static double question3(String county, String product, String paymentMethod)
{        
    double taxRate;

    if (county.equals("Dale"))
    {                       
        if (product.equals("Tobacco") || product.equals("Alcohol"))
        {
            if (paymentMethod.equals("Cash"))
                taxRate = 8.5;
            else if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
                taxRate = 4.5;
            else
                taxRate = 3.5;
        }

        else if (product.equals("Potato Chips") || product.equals("Soda Pop"))
        {
            if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
                taxRate = 4.0;
            else
                taxRate = 3.0;
        }

        else if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
            taxRate = 2.5;

        else
            taxRate = 1.5;
    }

    else if (county.equals("Richland"))
    {                        
        if (product.equals("Books"))
        {
            if (paymentMethod.equals("Credit"))
                taxRate = 2.0;
            else if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
                taxRate = 1.5;
            else
                taxRate = 1.0;
        }

        else if (product.equals("Clothing"))
        {
            if (paymentMethod.equals("Credit"))
                taxRate = 3.0;
            else if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
                taxRate = 2.5;
            else
                taxRate = 2.0;
        }

        else if (product.equals("Shoes"))
        {
            if (paymentMethod.equals("Credit"))
                taxRate = 4.0;
            else if (paymentMethod.equals("Check"))
                taxRate = 3.5;
            else
                taxRate = 3.0;
        }  
    }

    else if (county.equals("Park"))
    {            
        if (! product.equals("Food"))
        {
            if (product.equals("Alcohol"))
                taxRate = 5.0;
            else if (product.equals("Clothing") || product.equals("Shoes"))
                taxRate = 0.0;
            else
                taxRate = 3.0;
        }

        if (paymentMethod.equals("Cash") || paymentMethod.equals("Credit"))
        {
            if (! product.equals("Food"))
            {
                if (product.equals("Alcohol"))
                    taxRate = 5.0;
                else if (product.equals("Clothing") || product.equals("Shoes"))
                    taxRate = 0.0;
                else
                    taxRate = 2.0;
            }
            taxRate = 1.0;
        }

        else
            taxRate = 2.0;
    }

    else return Double.NaN;

    return 0; 
}
```

Each "county" has different laws and additional taxes based on the product and/or payment method (i.e. if you buy alcohol in Dale County with cash, the tax is 8.5%). The if and else if statements represent all the "special cases" where the taxes are either increased or reduced. The else statement at the end of each county block is the base tax rate for taxes in that county and is used on all other purchases (Dale is 1.5%, Richland is 3%, and Park is 2%).

What's happening here is that when I run the test case, no matter what the scenario, the value of taxRate comes out as 0.0, as if it's never had a value assigned to it. I hope I've provided enough information here, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I appreciate any help I get with this issue!

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: ..and what's the question?

Comment: The return 0; is not unreachable. It might be the reason why you always get 0.0 as an output :-))

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. It was as simple as returning the taxRate instead of 0. I didn't think that'd be the issue because the "return 0" line was defaulted into the program before I even coded it. The question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that *nowhere in your code do you return taxRate*, which is what you want to return..

```
else return Double.NaN;

return 0;
```

you need to return the taxRate so put this at the end of your code:

```
return taxRate;
```

you can initially set it to `Double.NaN` if that is what you want:

```
double taxRate = Double.NaN;
```

but at the end *only return taxRate* is what you need, *"no matter what the scenario"* as Jeroen correctly says in his comment!